# Align text vertically

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

How can I do something like this:

```
 blabla:   blabla bla bla blabla blabla bla
           blabla ...
blabla2:   blabla bla blabla bla bla blabla
           ablabla ..
```

I tried the `tabular` and `array` environements but it gives me long centred lines and don't return after the line reach the end of the page.

Comment: Is it necessary that this list be able to break across the page boundary? If not, you should look into the [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem).

Comment: `description` environment helps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two possible options: the first one uses a `tabular` environment; the second column is a `p{...}` column so the text will wrap; the width of this column was calculated so as to guarantee that the whole construct occupies the whole `\textwidth`; you can find basic information about the tabular environment in every introductory guide to LaTeX and in the documentation of the [`array`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package. The second solution uses a modified `description` environment; the settings were made using the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package. The first solution doesn't admit page breaks; the second one, does.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text for the example

\begin{document}

\newlength\Headwd
\settowidth\Headwd{Longer Text2:}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{:\hspace{1em}}p{\dimexpr\textwidth-1em-\Headwd\relax}@{}}
Text1 & \lipsum[2] \\
Longer Text2 &  \lipsum[2] \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{description}[
  before={\renewcommand\makelabel[1]{\makebox[2.5cm][l]{\hfill##1:\hspace{1em}}}},
  leftmargin=*,labelsep=0pt,itemindent=-2.5cm]
\item[Text1] \lipsum[2]
\item[Longer Text2]  \lipsum[2]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]